# Why is QGIS georeferencer much faster on Windows than Mac?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, performance, mac, windows

I just went from temporarily using a Windows 7 machine with 4GB of RAM and no video card as far as I know. I'm now using a mac with 16GB of ram, etc. Its a much more powerful machine.

However, QGis's georeferencer program runs about 8 times faster on the windows machine. Does anyone know why this is?

Gimp ran much faster too on the cheap windows machine.

Mac Specs:

- 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
- 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- OSX Version 10.9.5
- MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014
- Solid State Hard Drive

Windows Specs:

- 4GB RAM
- Windows 7
- Data on External Hard Drive (non-flash)

I'm guessing its something related to the fact that videogames tend to run better on windows platforms, viz. more time has been put into the win32 software graphics engines to display real time graphics..

Comment: Can you post more details like CPU/video card of the Mac, etc

Comment: What sort of storage are you accessing your data from on each machine i.e network drive, HDD, SSD...?

Comment: I swear its an operating system thing, a software problem. I think the graphics processing drivers on windows are just crushing the mac's in terms of hardware efficiency. This question should just as easily be "why is qgis so slow on macs". The mac's hardware is standard, its a very high end macbook pro purchased in 2014. The windows machine is at the office so I'll check on that on monday

Comment: The mac is 100% solid state memory! The windows machine reads from an external hard drive!! This has nothing to do with read/write speed of the data I think.

Comment: Please don't add information in comments, edit your question instead.

Comment: Anyone feel free to jump in. You can still give opinions in comments. I'm guessing its something related to the fact that videogames tend to run better on windows platforms, viz. more time has been put into the win32 software graphics engines to display real time graphics...

Comment: Could it be the CPU?  The i7 uses hyperthreading and has only 4 cores but uses hyperthreading to serve 2 threads per core.  The windows machine may have an 8 core processor.  If it does, and that has HT, the windows machine can work twice as fast.  I believe it would still be faster if the windows machine has an 8 core cpu without HT, because each core is dedicated to one thread per core.

Comment: Maybe you have a problem with faulty RAM? http://www.macworld.com/article/2362040/do-you-have-bad-ram-how-to-find-it-and-how-to-fix-it.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do some performance tuning in within QGIS on both the Windows and Mac machine. You can find this in Settings > Options > Rendering. QGIS is downloaded more on Windows than MACs. Boundless offers a Mac installer for QGIS. Checking the [documentation](https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/desktop/1.0.0/requirements.html#mac-system-requirements) for the system requirements for the version that you use can be beneficial too.